# Having Trouble Calling Other Class/Method

Tags: c++

I'm working on (I think I've completed correctly..?) a hashTable and have gotten all the way to the end where I've hit a little speed bump...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "hashTable.h"
#include <string>
#include <time.h>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

  clock_t start, end;
  double duration;

  start = clock();
    char firstLetter;
    string SSN, firstName, lastName, name; 
    fstream input(argv[1]);
    int count = 0;
    int numInserted = 0;
    int numDeleted = 0;
    int numRetrieved = 0;
    int numTable = 0;

  //Do I need these two? I’ve tried with and without them both/combination of neither
  //and gotten the same issue
  //Node<string>* node = new Node<string>;
  //SLL<string>* SLL = new SLL<string>;

  HashTable<string>* T = new HashTable<string>(10007);


    for(int i = 0; !input.eof(); i++){
        input >> firstLetter >> SSN >> firstName >> lastName;
        name = firstName + " " + lastName;

        switch(firstLetter){
            case 'd':{
                if(T.erase(SSN) == true){
                    numDeleted++;
                    numTable--;
                }
            }
            case 'i':{
                if(T.insert(SSN, name) == true){
                    numInserted++;
                    numTable++;
                }
            }
            case 'r':{
                if(T.find(SSN) == true){
                    numRetrieved++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    input.close();

  end = clock();
  duration = ( end - start ) / (double) CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
  cout << "The Numer of Valid Insertions: " << numInserted << endl;
  cout << "The Number of Valid Deletions: " << numDeleted << endl;
  cout << "The Number of Valid Retrievals: " << numRetrieved << endl;
  cout << "The Number of Items in Array: " << numTable << endl;
  cout<<"elapsed time: "<< duration <<'\n';
}
```

Above is my main.cpp file and it calls the hashTable.h (which calls my SLL.h which calls my node.h file) which has the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "SLL.h"
using  namespace  std;

template <class V>
class HashTable {
    int tableSize; // table size

    SLL<V>* table;

    public:
    // default constructor
    HashTable(){
        …
    }

    // constructor, which use size as the table size
    HashTable(int size){
      …
    }

    // search item in the table     
    // if found, return true; otherwise, return false
    bool find(V item){
      …
    }

    // insert (item1, item2) to the table
    // use item1 as the key
    // if inserted, return true
    // otherwise, return false
    bool insert(V item1, V item2){
      …
    }

    int HashFunc(V item1){
      …
    }

    // delete the pair whose key value is item
    // if deleted, return true
    // otherwise, return false 
    bool erase(V item){
      …
    }

    // return the total number of nodes in the hash table    
    int getSize(){
      …
    }
 };
```

After attempting to compile this without:

```
Node<string>* node = new Node<string>;
SLL<string>* SLL = new SLL<string>;
```

I get errors with T.erase/find/insert all stating the same thing asking if I meant to use '->'

After attempting to compile this with:

```
Node<string>* node = new Node<string>;
SLL<string>* SLL = new SLL<string>;
```

I get the same 3 errors above in addition to: "expected type-specifier before 'SLL' 
SLL< string>* SLL = new SLL;

If I need to add other code, let me know, I'll gladly do so.
Thanks for your assistance!

EDIT:
So when I compile it with

```
HashTable<string> T(10007);
```

I get like 50 errors from my hashTable.h all relating/correlating to me using -> in that file. So I'm pretty sure I have to use the pointer. Then I proceeded to switch the above to:

```
T->insert
T->find
T->erase
```

And I got 50 more errors after that from all ranges of things. At this point I have concluded that either: My code isn't that bad and it's something minor that has now screwed over everything or I just suck at programming and should retire while I'm behind :D That was when I compiled without SLL and  Node. So I tried compiling with those, got the same errors in addition to the expected type-specifier before 'SLL' again :[

Comment: `HashTable<string> T(10007);`

Comment: If you have `HashTable<string> T` then you can use operator dot to call functions `T.function()` if you have `HashTable<string>* T` (i.e., a pointer) you have to use operator -> (`T->function()`) or dereference and use operator dot (`(*T).function()`).

Comment: Do I include the * node and the * SLL lines or not when doing this?

Comment: "If I need to add other code, let me know, I'll gladly do so." - What you really need to do is provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, don't use `new` unless you **need** to. If you use `new` you must use `delete` (or `delete[]` for arrays) to avoid memory leaks but better yet use smart pointers (e.g., `std::unique_ptr`) to manage the memory for you.